# Jenkins, java.lang.NullPointerException, after deleting workspace

Tags: jenkins

This is the console output of the failure:

```
Started by user XXXXX
Building remotely on XXXXXin workspace /var/www/html/XXXXX
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
FATAL: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.model.Fingerprint.addWithoutSaving(Fingerprint.java:1035)
    at hudson.model.Fingerprint.add(Fingerprint.java:1030)
    at hudson.model.Fingerprint.addFor(Fingerprint.java:1023)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.trackAll(CredentialsProvider.java:1457)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.track(CredentialsProvider.java:1421)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:844)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:812)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1180)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1798)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Sending e-mails to: XXXXX@XXXXX.XXXXX
Finished: FAILURE
```

Just some jobs are getting this failure, what causes can be generating this failure?

Comment: Which jenkins version do you use?

Comment: @Jns Jenkins ver. 2.121.3. It seems that is a problem with git, but it's weird, why some jobs and not the others. We had a problem of disk space (too much logs) but after solve it and running up again Jenkins, those jobs starting to fail with github.

Comment: Could be related to this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-49588 I would try to stop jenkins, delete the content of {jenkins_home}/fingerprints and start jenkins again (as mentioned in that bug report).